# ArgumentOutOfRangeException com entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho um metodo que espera um objeto arquivo, o que ele faz é adicionar no banco de dados as referencias:

Vejam o método:

```
  internal void AddArquivo(Model.Arquivo arquivo)
    {
        using (var ctx = new TestEntities())
        {
            var versao = arquivo.ArquivoVersoes[0];
            ctx.ARQUIVO.Add(new ARQUIVO()
            {
                ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                ARQUIVO_VERSAO = new ARQUIVO_VERSAO()
                {
                    ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                    ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = versao.ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID,
                    ARQUIVO = versao.ARQUIVO,
                    DATAHORA = versao.DATAHORA,
                    TAMANHO = versao.TAMANHO,
                    USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID = versao.USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID
                },
                DIRETORIO_GUID = arquivo.DIRETORIO_GUID,
                EXTENSAO = arquivo.EXTENSAO,
                IS_STREAM = arquivo.IS_STREAM,
                TAG = arquivo.TAG,
                TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.TipoDeArquivo.TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID,
                ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = arquivo.ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID,
                URL = arquivo.URL,
                XARQUIVO = arquivo.XARQUIVO
            });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Porem ta dando o problema: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: O índice estava fora do intervalo. Ele deve ser não-negativo e menor que o tamanho da coleção.

Comment: Qual a linha em que o erro ocorre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se `arquivo.ArquivoVersoes` está nulo, você precisa usar um código que previna isso:

```
internal void AddArquivo(Model.Arquivo arquivo)
{
    using (var ctx = new TestEntities())
    {
        var versao = arquivo.ArquivoVersoes.FirstOrDefault();

        if (versao != null) 
        {
            ctx.ARQUIVO.Add(new ARQUIVO()
            {
                ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                ARQUIVO_VERSAO = new ARQUIVO_VERSAO()
                {
                    ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                    ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = versao.ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID,
                    ARQUIVO = versao.ARQUIVO,
                    DATAHORA = versao.DATAHORA,
                    TAMANHO = versao.TAMANHO,
                    USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID = versao.USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID
                },
                DIRETORIO_GUID = arquivo.DIRETORIO_GUID,
                EXTENSAO = arquivo.EXTENSAO,
                IS_STREAM = arquivo.IS_STREAM,
                TAG = arquivo.TAG,
                TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.TipoDeArquivo.TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID,
                ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = arquivo.ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID,
                URL = arquivo.URL,
                XARQUIVO = arquivo.XARQUIVO
            });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sumiu a exception, porem nada no banco. os outros metodos estao funcionando com o banco ja.

Comment: Se `ArquivoVersoes` está nulo, naturalmente que não vai salvar nada.

Comment: é mesmo, testei agora setando a versao e foi, valeu

Comment: como seto o ArquivoVersoes no c#?

Comment: @WarLock Pelo que eu entendi, `ArquivoVersoes` precisa ser preenchido de alguma forma. O seu código não deixa isso claro.

Comment: Eu tenho acesso a ele, no mesmo momento que vou passar o arquivo pra o metodo, antes de chamar esse metodo, eu seto arquivo, arquivo.XNOME ="Arquivox", arquivo.GUID="1", arquivoVersoes vem dentro de Arquivo tbm, entao ele é uma lista, como adiciono algo? o metodo Add não aparece.

Comment: @WarLock Não sei. Isso deveria ser colocado em outra pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o erro aconteça aqui

```
var versao = arquivo.ArquivoVersoes[0];
```

Verifique se existe algum registro dentro de **ArquivoVersoes**

Assim

```
    var versao = new ArquivoVersoes();
    if(arquivo.ArquivoVersoes != null && arquivo.ArquivoVersoes.Count() > 0)
       versao = arquivo.ArquivoVersoes[0];
```

Comment: realmente ele vai vim nulo, mas como faço para adicionar o arquivo então.

Comment: Atualizei, vê se te ajuda.

Comment: ArquivoVersoes.Length da erro, nao acha o length

Comment: Tenta com COUNT

Comment: continua dando a mesma exception

Comment: Qual exception ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20897/discussion-between-war-lock-and-paulohdsousa).